# Pass value from one php function to other function without calling function

Tags: php, variables

> Using **global variable** how can I use value of one function to pass on to other function **without** calling a function?

**LIKE**

```
$toshik;
function one()
{
  global $toshik;
  $toshik=2;
}

function two()
{
 one();
  global $toshik;
  echo $toshik; [//this should give value as **2**]
}
?>
```

Comment: Typo: fuction. However without calling one() of course nothing in it gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 scenarios here (following up on your code).

```
// file 1
two(); // echoes nothing
// file 2
one();
two(); // echo 2
```

There is no third way. What are you trying to accomplish by the way ?

Comment: when i echo variable in two() function in query it shows empty!!

Comment: well, yes, that's what I said in the comment. If you don't call `one()` first, it will be empty.

Answer (score 2):

1st: you probably meant `global $toshik;` in your functions.

2nd: You can't do that. A function is meant to be called. It does nothing till you call it, so, naturally, the variable is not set.

If you just need a single variable from your function and not the rest, set up some conditions like `function one( $set = false )` and after that change the function to set only the variable, if the `$set == true`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$var = 1;
foo();     // outputs: 1
bar();     // outputs: 2
echo $var; // outputs: 3

function foo() {
    global $var;
    echo $var; // -> 1
    $var++;
}


function bar() {
    global $var;
    echo $var; // -> 2
    $var++;
}
```

You've updated your question after my answer. What you posted should work. You will of course have to call the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try reference of valriable....

`$toshik;
function one(&$toshik){
  global $toshik;
  $toshik=2;
}
function two(){
  global $toshik;
  one();
  echo $toshik; 
}
two();`